# Table without a primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

So I've always been told that it's absolutely necessary to have a primary key specified with a table. I've been doing some work and ran into a situation where a primary key's unique constraint would stop data I need from being added.

If there's an example situation where a table was structured with fields:

```
Age, First Name, Last Name, Country, Race, Gender
```

Where if a TON of data was being entered all these fields don't necessarily uniquely identify a row and I don't need an index across all columns anyways. Would the only solution here be to make an auto-incrementing ID field? Would it be okay to NOT have a primary at all?

Comment: "a primary key's unique constraint would stop data I need from being added" How so?

Comment: You can use a composite primary key, i.e. a primary key made up of more than one column.

Comment: I'd personally key on unique, auto-increment row id and create secondary indexes on the combination of columns that I'd need to search on, for example lastname+firstname. Use the row id in any other tables that reference rows in this table.

Comment: The trouble with a composite primary key is that, even if you include _all_ columns in it, it's not necessarily unique across the entire domain (two thirty-year-old transsexual Italians living in New York, both called Guido Del Mar, for example). A surrogate key, on the other hand, is unique by definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not always necessary to have a primary key, most DBMS' will allow you to construct a table without one <sup>(a)</sup>.

But that doesn't necessarily mean it's a good idea. Have a think about the situation in which you want to use that data. Now think about if you have two twenty-year-old Australian men named Bob Smith, both from Perth.

Without a unique constraint, you can *put* both rows into the table but her's the rub. How would you figure out which one you want to use in future? <sup>(b)</sup>

Now, if you just want to store the fact that there are one or more people meeting those criteria, you only need to store *one* row. But then, you'd probably have a composite primary key consisting of *all* columns.

If you have other information you want to store about the person (e.g., highest score in the "2048" game on their iPhone), then you *don't* want a primary key across the entire row, just across the columns you mention.

Unfortunately, that means there will undoubtedly come a time when both of those Bob Smith's try to write their high score to the database, only to find one of them loses their information.

If you want them both in the table and still want to allow for the possibility outlined above (two people with identical attributes in the columns you mention) then the best bet is to introduce an artificial key such as an auto-incrementing column, for the primary key. That will allow you to uniquely identify a row regardless of how identical the other columns are.

The other advantage of an artificial key is that, being arbitrary, it never needs to change for the thing being identified. In your example, if you use age, names, nationality or location <sup>(c)</sup> in your primary key, these are *all* subject to change, meaning that you will need to adjust any foreign keys referencing those rows. If the tables referencing these rows uses the unchanging artificial key, that will never be a problem.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> There are situations where a primary key doesn't really give you any performance benefit such as when the table is particularly small (such as mapping integers 1 through 12 to month name).

In other words, things where a full table scan isn't really any slower than indexing. But these situations are incredibly rare and I'd probably still use a key because it's more consistent (especially since the use of a key tends not to make a difference to the performance *either* way).

---

<sup>(b)</sup> Keep in mind that we're talking in terms of practice here rather than theory. While in practice you may create a table with no primary key, relational theory states that each row must be uniquely identifiable, otherwise relations are impossible to maintain.

C.J. Date who, along with Codd, is one of the progenitors of relational database theory, states the rules of relational tables in "An introduction to Database Systems", one of which is:

> The records have a unique identifier field or field combination called the primary key.

So, in terms of relational *theory,* each table must have a primary key, even though it's not always required in practice.

---

<sup>(c)</sup> *Particularly* age which is guaranteed to change annually until you're dead, so perhaps date of birth may be a better choice for that column.

Answer (score 3):

> Would the only solution here be to make an auto-incrementing ID field?

That is a valid way, but it is not the only one: you could use other ways to generate unique keys, such as using [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)s. Keys like that are called *surrogate primary keys*, because they are not related to the "payload" of the data row.

> Would it be okay to NOT have a primary at all?

Since you mentioned that the actual data in rows may not be unique, you wouldn't be able to use your table effectively without a primary key. For example, you would not be able to update or delete a specific row, which may be required, for example, when a user's name changes.

Comment: Is there any benefit to a GUID over a auto-increment?

Comment: @KevinBowersox Yes, in situations when you would like to produce an in-memory representation of a new object with a GUID PK without a roundtrip to RDBMS, GUID lets you do it. Another benefit is merging objects created by the same application running against different databases: GUID lets you reconcile records without any additional work.

Answer (score 3):

The most simple solution would be to include an ID column to serve as primary key:

```
id int not null primary key auto_increment
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically you should avoid proliferating ID primary keys fields through your database.

Now, that doesn't mean you shouldn't have primary keys, your primary key can be a surrogate or a composed key. And that's what you should do here.

If those fields {Age, First Name, Last Name, Country, Race, Gender}, identify unequivocally each row, then make a primary key composed by all of those fields.

But if not, then you must have some other type of information to disambiguate your data.

You can also, not specify any kind of key, and assume that table as non-normalized, and redundant data source... if this is what you need...!

Comment: Why you should avoid adding IDs to tables? Can you expand why is that a good idea? Also, surrogate and composite keys are two completely different concepts, not synonyms.

Comment: A surrogate is a primary key with no business meaning, the composed key is just composed by more than one column... About the ID proliferation avoidance, you should avoid adding and ID to a table without thinking, there are many cases where your fields provide enough unique info to make a primary key. (I edited my answer, thanks for your comment)

Answer (score 1):

From your post it looks like the table representing a `person` entity. In that case, wouldn't having a PK would determine each person entity uniquely. I would suggest, having a primary key on the table which will uniquely determine each person record.

You can either create a `AUTO_INCREMENT` ID column (a synthetic ID column)

(OR)

You can combine multiple columns in your table which can uniquely determine all the other fields like `(First Name, Last Name)` probably which will make it a composite primary key but that may clash as well since there could be more than one person having same full name (first name + last name).

Answer (score 0):

Use an identity column with another column such as Last Name